# How can we define the Ordered Union of events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider an urn $C$ which contains three (distinguishable) kinds of elements, say $\alpha>0$ elements of kind $A$, $\beta>0$ elements of kind $B$, and $\gamma>0$ elements of kind $G$.

We perform $n>0$ trials (with replacement) of one element at a time from the urn $C$.

We define the event $L^{AB}_n$: "to get at least one element of kind $A$ and at least one element of kind $G$, in $n$ trials".

The probability to get a success for this event in correspondence of the trial $k\in\{1,2\ldots n\}$ is

$$
P(L^{AB}_k)=1-\left(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\right)^k-\left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\right)^k+\left(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}\right)^k.
$$

Moreover, it clearly holds the relation

> $$
> P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n L_{k}^{AB})=P(L_n^{AB}).
> $$

The union of the events (as expressed above) naturally does not take into account the *order* in which they occur. But, in our case, it is not possible to get success for the event $L^{AB}_k$ *but not* for the event $L^{AB}_{k+1}$ (or any following other).

In other words, it seems to me that one should introduce the concept of *ordered union* of these events.

> **Is there any definition of such concept?**

Comment: Can you make the urn "G" (or "U", or just call it an urn), and the third kind "C"?

Comment: I don't see a reason to define an ordered union (other than to make indexing easy).  The events themselves can specify the "times" they occur, if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept you are looking for is a *chain of nested events*, similar to a chain of nested sets, where each event is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ in the probability space you are considering, so each event is a subset of the sample space $\Omega$ and is a subset of the next larger event, i.e. $L^{AB}_{k-1}\subseteq L^{AB}_{k}$

More fully you have  $L^{AB}_1 \subseteq L^{AB}_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq L^{AB}_{k-1}\subseteq L^{AB}_{k}\subseteq \cdots\subseteq L^{AB}_{n}$ so implying $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n L_{k}^{AB}=L_n^{AB}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Henry. However, there's no way to take into account (in the union) of the fact that it cannot be $L_k^{AB} \subset L_{k-1}^{AB}$?

Comment: I am not sure about the double negative in your comment, but it is possible to  say that (a) the union of a finite chain of nested sets is the largest set, (b) here  $L_k^{AB} \nsubseteq L_{k-1}^{AB}$ and $\mathbb P (L_k^{AB}) >  \mathbb P (L_{k-1}^{AB})$, and (c) here you could define $L_\infty^{AB} = \sup_k  L_{k}^{AB} =\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty L_{k}^{AB}$ and this event has probability $\mathbb P (L_\infty^{AB})= 1$ and so is almost certain